# Don't trigger child-checkbox onclick parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm working on an AJAX based filter with a list of items a user can check on or off. Their structure is like so:

```
<a href="#" class="someidentifier"><input type="checkbox"> Filter label</a>
```

The checkbox really only serves as a visual reminder if it's active or not. Clicking the link applies or removes the filter and checks or unchecks the box.

Now the problem is that whenever users click directly on the checkbox, it just checks/unchecks the box without any action. Preferably what I want is for the checkbox to 'hide behind' the anchor tag. Click either the label, the checkbox or the space in between; it should all resolve in the same action.
Earlier I saw people 'fix' this by imitating the checkbox with a static background image, however this could/would work, this would 'break' interface design as checkboxes are styled differently across browsers and platforms.

I've tried the following:

Make the checkboxes `disabled` (No luck)

Setting the checkbox.click action in jQuery to just `stopPropagation()`

Adding `onclick="this.parentNode.click()"` to the checkbox - Now this one seems to work, except it fires the click double (once for the  and once for the checkbox), quickly enabling/disabling the filter at once.

Is there any HTML/CSS/jQuery to just make that inline checkbox sit in the back, behind a glass plate so that no user-interaction could reach it and instead is controlled by the parent anchor?

Comment: You cannot have `<input />` inside `<a>`. The syntax isn't semantic, so... `:)`

Comment: Oh? That's news to me, though I guess it makes sense. I guess I could switch up the markup and have the checkbox and anchor next to eachother with the same action..

Comment: Yeah, mate. That might work. Just FYI, putting it inside a label will make it clickable too. You know that right?

Comment: Yes, that was (of course) the first thing I did. But adding a label to the markup messed up the entire functionality of the entire script in such a way that it wasn't worth it to figure that out, rather then to fix this one thing. Anyway, thx for setting me on the right path!